# Random Sampling from Druid Databases

Tags: r, random, dataset, druid

I've just started using Druid, specifically with RDruid and as our dataset is quite large, I'd like to pull a smaller, randomized sample from the DB.

Using RDruid I have a query that looks like:

```
res2 = druid.query.groupBy(
  url = druid.url("hostname", port=8080),
  dataSource   = "playback",
  intervals    = interval(
    fromISO("2013-09-20T00:00:00"),
    now()
  ),
  dimensions = list(dimension("platformInfo_deviceType"), dimension("isp")),
  granularity="hour",
  aggregations = list(
    sum(metric("streamStartCount"))
  )
)
```

I would like to have it build the hourly/minutely rollups on a random portion of the underlying data.

Is this even possible?  Maybe I could try something like assigning a random 4 digit number/string to the underlying data records and apply a filter which only rolls up records with matching rules.

E.g. if the random string is > 8888 then it would select all records between 8889 and 9999.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you will show me how to pull the n-th record, I will show you how to sample any particular number of records at (pseudo)-random intervals.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sample.big.n <- function(n, max) trunc(runif(n, max=max+1))

 sample.big.n(5, 1e9)
[1] 960118066 734686176 291924461 238165419 195301121
 sample.big.n(5, 1e9)
[1] 682097669 519657711 435974111 420722901 266094914
 sample.big.n(5, 1e9)
[1] 134806446 281796597 595062788 551378278 648440525
```

Added 1 to max to give the last record an equal chance with the rest. There should be probability approaching 0 (or at least being no greater than 1e-16) of `runif` returning the end-point of the interval.